# It is possible to skip/fail test in setup using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest and hope to check:

Is it possible to conditionally skip/fail tests (grouped in class) in setup?

Comment: You can use pytest.mark.skipif decorator for your test class, can't you?

Comment: I hope to control it in setup stage. For example in setup_module. But it looks doesn't work with decorator.

Comment: In that case you can write a function pytest_ignore_collect in your conftest.py, it's called during collecting tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `pytest.skip(...)` and `pytest.fail(...)` there. See "[Imperative xfail from within a test or setup function](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#imperative-xfail-from-within-a-test-or-setup-function)" in the docs.